# using coordinate variables

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have some problems with the javascript for my user coordinates. In all examples they print an alert message on the return callback from geolocation, but I want to use the lat,long coordinates for printing or setting other values. What is the problem with this code? Can anyone be kind and explain: :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

function success(position) {
 var lat = position.coords.latitude;
 var long = position.coords.longitude;
}

document.write(lat);
</script>
```

and this is the errorcode with phonegap:

> 05-12 16:40:35.486: E/Web Console(15962): ReferenceError: Can't find
>   variable: lat at file:///android_asset/www/showMap/showMap.html:31

Thanks

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Answer (score 3):

You've declared `lat` and `long` inside the `success` function, so that is where they are scoped to. You cannot access them outside the `success` function.

You could change your code to something like:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

function success(position) {
 var lat = position.coords.latitude;
 var long = position.coords.longitude;
 // lat is accessible inside "success", we can write out the variable here:
 document.write(lat);
}
```

Just to be clear, even *if* you made `lat` and `long` global here it wouldn't help you. `success` is executed **asynchronously** after `getCurrentPosition` has finished running.

Comment: @user1391179 the only correct solution is to move dependent code into `success`. Welcome to callbacks and asynchrony.